# How to integrate a .js file within an infoWindow?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, animation

I have downloaded a plug-in from Github, and have followed the instructions to install it into a webpage.

The problems occur when I try to trigger the jQuery animation via a click on a button I have placed in an infoWindow in Google Maps.

I know the code package I downloaded works as it comes with a demo, so I suspect its the method I am using to call the function.

here is the code describing the info window and button in the home.js file:

```
var contentString = 
  '<div id="content" style="width:300px; height:400px; background-color:white; border-radius: 2px 2px 2px 2px;">' 
    + 
      '<img border="0" src="/siteImages/brickWall.jpg" style=" position:relative; top:0; width:100%; height:200px; left: 0 !important; right: 0 !important;">' 
     + 
      '<button **onclick= "loadMenu();"** style="width: 80px; height: 10px ">' + 'Full Menu' + '</button>' 
      + 
      '<div id="infoMain" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; overflow-y: scroll; text-align: justify; width:400px; height: 66vh">'  
        +  
         '<h1>' + 'Here is The Heading' + '</h1>' 
        + 
         '<p>' + 'Randomness is the lack of pattern or predictability in events.' + '</p>' 
    + '</div>' 

  + '</div>';
```

[1] A random sequence of events, symbols or steps has no order and does not follow an intelligible pattern or combination. Individual random events are by definition unpredictable, but in many cases the frequency of different outcomes over a large number of events (or "trials") is predictable. For example, when throwing two dice, the outcome of any particular roll is unpredictable, but a sum of 7 will occur twice as often as 4. In this view, randomness is a measure of uncertainty of an outcome, rather than haphazardness, and applies to concepts of chance, probability, and information entropy.

```
var var_infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: contentString,
   styles: [
             {

             }
           ]
      });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker3, 'click', function() {
        var_infowindow.open(map,marker3);
    });
```

and this is how I am calling the animation from the jquery-square_menu.js script:

```
function loadMenu() {

  $.getScript("my_lovely_script.js", function(){

      alert("Script loaded but not necessarily executed.");

   });
}
```

There is also an jquery-square_menu.min.js, which I'm not really sure about how it fits in.

When I run the code and press the button nothing happens, when I click the button with the console open, I am getting the error can't find variable: $

Any help on this would be appreciated, I'm quite new to programming and have been stuck on this for a few days now.

Answer (score 0):

`can't find variable: $` usually means jQuery is not defined. Do you have jquery

Comment: I downloaded jQuery, can you tell me how I would implement it in the code I am trying to run?